# What is the best flow diagram if you have multiple processes and projects tied together like so

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have used flow charts in school and in an attempt to create a less generic chart, I figured I will share the processes and data I wish to organize.. see what ideas are available for this complex project. I do have access to Visio.

I have a local wamp server (no database) that runs processes, two remote servers with a database each (all tied together), local excel files that have a good amount of manual process and linked to local server, submitted files by vendors to manually update into excel files, an admin GUI for each remote server (one is e-commerce and one is data analysis). Also I am running cron's from cpanel and Windows Task Scheduler for local. Also, I am updating products on Amazon and Google, while using googles API.

I am looking for what diagram to use and what naming conventions (and shapes) will be unique in this scenario to better make sense.

Comment: @fixer1234 Do you typically find old posts (4 years old!) and go in to edit, then down vote! Not very productive in my opinion.

Comment: if you look at the edit history, all I did was delete a tag that was part of a tag cleanup effort.  Over 10K rep, that can be done without even opening the question to edit it.  I see that I voted to close a month earlier.  I'm guessing that I discovered the post while looking at the [organization] tag, asked on Meta about cleaning up the tag, the cleanup was recommended, and then I cleaned up the tag on all applicable posts.  I didn't downvote.  I rarely do, reserving that only for truly bad posts that can't be fixed or that provide dangerously wrong answers (check my profile).

Comment: @fixer1234 got it, sorry for the insinuation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just looking for specific Viso Stencils which correspond to the services you're referencing, take a look at http://www.visiocafe.com/index.htm for a wide variety of Viso Stencils.

However, if you're asking a more general, "how to diagram this setup," this depends on your audience.

Are you trying to document for:

- Your own purposes to understand the setup?
- Your peers to help them understand/support the setup?
- Your non-technical management?

Each of these scenarios require different levels of detail.  If you are documenting for non-technical management, you would probably want to KISS.  However, your peers would benefit from more detailed documentation.

However, please keep in mind the following from Charles Galler over at [PacketPushers](http://packetpushers.net/network-documentation-best-practices-whats-important-how-to-track-it/):

> One of my pet peeves is ‘pretty’ drawings that have the product icon of the device or the PowerPoint symbol of the device’s function. That’s fine if you are in sales and you draw in PowerPoint. For us engineers, the object representing the device needs to be simple and useful. The objects I use in my drawings are typically three different shapes; rectangles for switches (and other devices), circles for routers, and hexagrams for firewalls. This keeps it easy to draw and consistent. Since I use these simple shapes, I can put details about that device within the object itself.

Hope this helps!

-Brett

Comment: Thanks Brett, I believe I am trying to "understand the setup" and for an easy reference as I make changes. I am taking on another persons project, so I have to learn it rapidly, so a map for myself and ease the process of altering. It also can serve visual for "non-technical" management to justify time on this part of the project and value as to explaining to others the process. So it might need some "pretty" for that part. I will go over some of your links as well...